# Rearrange and Sort

Tags: r, binary, reshape

I have the following data

```
ID v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 
1  1  3  6  4
2  4  2
3  3  1   8    5
4  2  5   3    1
```

Can I rearrange the data so that it will automatically create new columns and assign binary value (1 or 0) according to the value in each variable (v1 to v5)?

E.g. In first row, I have values of 1,3,4 and 6. Can R automatically create 6 dummy variables to have assign the value to the respective column as below:

```
 ID dummy1 dummy2 dummy3 dummy4 dummy5 dummy6
 1    1     0      1      1      0       1
```

To have something like this:

```
ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
2  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
3  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
4  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
```

Thanks.

Comment: `melt` and then `dcast` the data using "data.table" (or `gather` and `spread` using the "tidyverse").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `base R` to do this.  Loop through the rows of the dataset except the first column, get the sequence of `max` value in the row, check how many of these are in the row and convert it to `integer` with `as.integer`, append `NA`s at the end to make the lengths same in the `list` output and `cbind` with the first column

```
lst <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) as.integer(seq_len(max(x, na.rm = TRUE)) %in% x))
res <- cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))))
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
colnames(res)[-1] <- paste0('c', 1:8)
res
#  ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
#1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
#2  2  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
#3  3  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
#4  4  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can use:

```
table(transform(cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1]))[1:2], values = factor(values, 1:8)))
##    values
## ID  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
##   1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
##   2 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
##   3 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
##   4 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Note that you need to convert the stacked values to `factor` if you want the "7" to be included in the output. This applies to the "data.table" and "tidyverse" approaches as well.

---

Alternatively, you can try the following with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(mydf), "ID", na.rm = TRUE)[
  , dcast(.SD, ID ~ factor(value, 1:8), fun = length, drop = FALSE)]
```

Or the following with the "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>% 
  gather(var, val, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-var) %>% 
  mutate(var = 1, val = factor(val, 1:8)) %>% 
  spread(val, var, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
```

---

Sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, v1 = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), v2 = c(3L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L), v3 = c(6L, NA, 8L, 3L), v4 = c(4L, NA, 5L, 1L), v5 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"), row.names = c(NA, 
    4L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

If automation is important, you can also use syntax like `factor(value, sequence(max(value))` in the "data.table" approach or `val = factor(val, sequence(max(val))))` in the "tidyverse" approach.

Answer (score 3):

Another base R answer with some similarities to akrun's is

```
# create matrix of values
myMat <- as.matrix(dat[-1])
# create result matrix of desired shape, filled with 0s
res <- matrix(0L, nrow(dat), ncol=max(myMat, na.rm=TRUE))
# use matrix indexing to fill in 1s
res[cbind(dat$ID, as.vector(myMat))] <- 1L
# convert to data.frame, add ID column, and provide variable names
setNames(data.frame(cbind(dat$ID, res)), c("ID", paste0("c", 1:8)))
```

which returns

```
  ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
2  2  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
3  3  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
4  4  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
```